# Strategy pattern modification

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern

How to modify classic strategy pattern in case when each ConcreteStrategy talks to DataStorage? There are different types of data storage and the interface depends on the concrete strategy.

Comment: It would be great if you made this question more self contained. Explain the pattern shortly and the issue you are facing when applying it to the target domain. +1 for asking about design patterns!

Answer (score 1):

Make your strategies dependent on DataStorage via constructor injection. Then each strategy can use DataStorage as they please.

If DataStorage implements many interfaces, make each strategy dependent on that particular interface.

Answer (score 0):

A brief answer could be:

First Define your common interfaces for data storage like:

```
Query()
Update()
Delete()
Add()
Create()
```

Second, implement these interfaces in each concrete data storage implementation class.

When you use these class objects, you call the method via interface methods, the real task carrier is the specific object.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that pattern is just general thing. You can do whatever you need to make that pattern work in your situation. You can combine your strategy with Factory, Memento, etc. Right now everybody talks about "injecting". But using interfaces has been around for long time.

```
public class ConcreteStrategy : IStrategy 
{
    protected IDatastorage _dataStrorage;
}
```

This should do it